# Not able to control DC motor speed with l298N & pwm pins

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm, l298n

I am using arduino uno to control dc motor speed with L298N. But the problem is that the motor is only going at max speed. PWM pin doesn't work for some reason.
I heard many people had some problem but haven't found the solution yet.

code:-

```
#include <L298N.h>

#define ENA 9
#define IN1 8
#define IN2 7

L298N motor(ENA, IN1, IN2);

void setup() {
// Setup pin mode

//used for display information
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
//Drive Motor Forward
  motor.setSpeed(10);
  motor.forward();
  delay(500);
  motor.setSpeed(100);
  motor.forward();
  delay(500);
  motor.setSpeed(255);
  motor.forward();
  delay(500);

}
```

I only see the motor move at full speed every time. I connected 5V of Arduino to +12V pin of motor driver and Arduino is powered with my laptop USB.

I am using 4.5V toy dc motor for test - [DC motor](https://uae.souq.com/ae-en/dc-geared-motors-for-robots-straight-shaft-12139874/i/?a_source=google&a_medium=cpc&a_content=search_shopping&u_type=shopping&a_campaign=Shopping-Smart-UAE-EN-Global&referrer=re%3D1%26a%3Damodi%26ca%3DGoogle-Shopping-Smart-1018320391%26an%3DGoogle%20Search%26p%3DAndroid%26pl%3D45586436090%26cr%3D-%26s%3D&gclid=CjwKCAjwhbHlBRAMEiwAoDA34xlPRdDs2_k7X-qV8erCRBm9ERJz3M0s-0CaZYC5dPhSB717S_m1DhoCvpUQAvD_BwE)

What could be wrong here?

Comment: The l298n output to the motor has a large voltage drop, and because of that it will not work with 5v. The 5v pin of the arduino can not supply enough current for a motor. What motor is it? Can you give a link to the motor?

Comment: added dc motor link, I am using those toy dc motor for the test. It doesn't need much voltage so I though it will be fine.

Comment: That is a small motor. With a mosfet driver (no voltage drop) it might work with the 5v pin.

Comment: this motor is just for test. Later I want to control 12V high torque motor so for that, I am using this module.

Comment: Using 5V pin (!) of an USB-powered Arduino (!!) as a motor power supply (!!!) can easily kill your Arduino.

Comment: **Similar problem solved:** I had a similar problem with the motors running att full speed with analogwrite values higher than 127 and not running at 127 or below.
After some research i found out that **only some pins works for pwm** [reference for analogWrite()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/), but your ENA is on pin 9, and that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the library code file L298N.cpp. Insert 2 lines in setSpeed():

```
void L298N::setSpeed(unsigned short pwmVal)
{ _pwmVal = pwmVal;
  if (_ismoving == true)                   // +++
    analogWrite(_pinEnable, _pwmVal);      // +++
}
```

Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code, without the library, and be sure to connect every pin to the correct Arduino output. If everything is okay it should work. Check the tutorial [here](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-dc-motor-control-tutorial-l298n-pwm-h-bridge/)

```
int IN3 = 5;    
int IN4 = 4;     
int ENB = 3;    
void setup()
{
 pinMode (ENB, OUTPUT); 
 pinMode (IN3, OUTPUT);
 pinMode (IN4, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  
  digitalWrite (IN3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (IN4, LOW);   
  analogWrite(ENB,55);
  delay(2000);
  analogWrite(ENB,105);
  delay(2000);
  analogWrite(ENB,255);
  delay(2000);
  analogWrite(ENB,0);
  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: I did try that code also but didn't work. I think there is problem in the enable pin of driver itself.